# Change SVN URL repository in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Our SVN repository has moved to a new location. I need to reconfigure the jenkins so that it points to the new location and start building from there. Jenkins runs in a remote UNIX server.

Is it sufficient if I change the SVN URL in the source code management section in the jenkins UI page? or do I need to grep for the SVN url in the jenkins directory by logging  into the unix server and start replacig every occurence of it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sufficient to change the SVN URL in the job configuration. Jenkins will remove the existing checkout and start anew. If the job has fixed slave, you can delete the workspace manually in the slave to fasten the process.